# In watsonx Asisstant actions how can I get a list of ID's and titles through the API

Tags: watson-assistant

I want to be able to pull the ID and title of each action contained within the assistant using the API. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API does not directly have this feature. You will need to download the skill using the [export skills](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant-v2#exportskills) API.

Then with the action json you can read the `workspace.actions[]` objects for the `action` (id) and `title` attributes.

The following is sample python code to show the values:

```
import json

with open('example-action.json') as file:
    skill = json.load(file)

workspace = skill.get('workspace', {})
actions = workspace.get('actions', [])

for action in actions:
    id = action.get('action', '')
    title = action.get('title', '')

    print(f'{id} : {title}')
```